# How to change apple watch interface controller title size/text?

Tags: apple-watch

How to change apple watch `interface controller` title size/text ?
Can we provide custom fonts ?
Tries with setting title programmatically using `NSAttributedText` but no success.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you find any answer to this question?

Comment: @rordulu:  apple watch interface controller title `size` cannot be changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the interface controller's title by calling:
swift : `func setTitle(_ title: String?)`
objc: `- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title`
For now we can't change the title text size or use a custom font for the title.

Comment: Yes, you can see the class reference WKInterfaceController, Setting the Display Title section. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/

Comment: @Vojcekushevski can we set navigation title in center ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha I am not sure if this is available in the latest watchkit sdk, but i think there is no option to align the navigation title.
- One thing you can do (quite hacky and i don't recommend it) is to add spaces before the title @"       Title", and this eventually will move the title towards the middle of the screen. Note that you will have to have different amount of 'spaces' on 38'' and 42'' devices and you will have problem if the app is localized :) Also think if in future there can be different devices ...