# Is there anyway I can change the size of the title for an apple watch app?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

Is there anyway I can change the size of the title for an apple watch app?
The one that shows up on top left corner.

Comment: It might be more helpful to add some code, or show us what you've tried. If any errors were thrown, add those to the question as well.

Comment: I tried [self setTitle:@"Title"] to set the title of the app on the apple watch and this sets the title and I can see it but I was wondering if I can set a size of the title like we do on iPhone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change apple watch interface controller title size/text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083467/how-to-change-apple-watch-interface-controller-title-size-text)

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CreatingtheUserInterface.html) It's the Apple development guide.

[Also look into this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UILabel.html) It's specific to Apple Watch App labels.

**Edit**:

[This link specifically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797) has the methods and properties used to resize label text within an Apple Watch App.

Both of these were found via a simple Google search. If you want help with a code block specifically, please edit your original question to add that code.

Comment: How do you get hold of the UILabel used to display the title?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. You can "kind of" solve it by using a group. Paste the group in, layer it over with another group and put the label inside there, change your label size by dragging the corners. That centers it. I don't think Apple has added the capability to freely move around labels like iOS View Controllers. I hope that helps for now :)